# AltGr key in Sublime Text 2 on Linux

Tags: linux, keyboard-shortcuts, sublimetext2

Is it possible to bind the AltGr key in Sublime Text 2 on Linux as a modifier?

In Windows one can use `"keys": ["ctrl+alt+<some_key>"]`.

How would i do this in Linux as `"keys": ["altgr+<some_key>"]` doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Look like <kbd>altGr</kbd> work as <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd> on windows, both shortuct does the same thing on my keyboard.

As exemple : <kbd>altGr</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> type '€' and <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>e</kbd> type '€' too (french keyboard layout)

Comment: In the german keyboard layout this doesn't work on Linux Ubuntu 16.10

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe so. The [list of modifier keys](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/key_bindings.html#modifiers) in the docs only has <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd>, and <kbd>Super</kbd> (Win/Cmd). <kbd>AltGr</kbd> is not addressable on its own through Sublime keymaps.

Answer (score 0):

The best way I've found to get around this is to add a key binding for the character <kbd>altGr</kbd> + <kbd>any-key</kbd> produces. Won't work for all combinations since not all keys produce a character with altGr, but should work for those that do.

e.g `{ "keys": ["ł"], "command": "insert", "args": {"characters": "L"} }` would insert `L` for the key combination <kbd>altGr</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> (given `ł` is produced by that combo on your setup)